# Mounting a local directory in Minikube causes "File system loop detected" error when a pod uses it

Tags: mount, minikube

I would like to run MongoDB in Minikube, while mounting a local directory to the pod so that MongoDB can use the data in it. My data is in the ./data directory of my local PC, so I first did this:

`minikube mount ./data:/mnt/mongodata`

The mounting had no problem, I could successfully find the data in the /mnt/mongodata in minikube using `minikube ssh` and then `ls /mnt/mongodata`.

Next I tried to create the persistent volume (PV), the persistent volume claim (PVC), and also the deployment and service as follows.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-vol
  labels:
    folder: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/mongodata"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 512Mi

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mongo2-deployment
  labels:
    app: mongo2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo2
    spec:
      volumes:
      - name: mongodata
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: mongo-pv-claim
      containers:
      - name: mongo2db
        image: mongo:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data/db"
          name: mongodata

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongo2-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  selector:
    app: mongo2
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 27017
      targetPort: 27017
```

But after running `kubectl apply -f mongo.yaml`, the mongo2-deployment pod got an error, and when I looked at the log using `kubectl logs deployment/mongo2-deployment`, the error is:

`find: File system loop detected; '/data/db/diagnostic.data' is part of the same file system loop as '/data/db'.`

When I tried not to mount the local directory, or changed the mount path (to say "/data/db2"), the pod ran correctly. I suppose MongoDB generated a default database in the /data/db directory in such case, but then I would not be able to access my data.

Why was the mounting not successful and caused the File system loop error? I suppose the mounting should "cover" the original /data/db directory, if there was one. And what should I do to fix the problem?